# 1 wordpress and 1 regular php website in one databse

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, sharing

I have a godaddy starter hosing plan which offers only one mysql database. I already have a wordpress website installed on it. I want to install another non-wordpress php website on it which also requires a database. I want to know if it is possible for both to share one database. Both are different websites with different content and i want to use the same domain with a subdomain for the later one.
please help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, two sites can share a database, each with it's own tables.  Definitely use a namespace on your tables to easily identify which tables belong to which app.

Comment: thank you very much for your response,. So the new import of a database which have different namespace will not break my already installed wordpress installation right,.And one more question please how can i setup a subdomain for the other website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same database with both websites by adding a prefix to all the tables of one of the sites. By default, WordPress prefixes all of its tables with `wp_` so as long as none of your tables for the other website start with `wp_` you shouldn't need to prefix any of the new websites tables.